# Is it possible to disambiguate instances with an intermediate step?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, proof

Suppose a scenario where you have an application config, the structure of which has changed a few times. To provide ease of use for users, you wish to allow automatic migration from each version to the next.

The code below shows such a scenario, representing the configuration as `VersionedConfig`, which is parameterised over the version of the configuration structure.

Given it is possible to migrate between any two successive versions (`V1 -> V2`, `V2 -> V3` and so on), is it possible to write an instance of `MigrateableFromTo` which composes those instances in the correct order to form the complete set of changes?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

-- | Represents different versions of a config file
data ConfigVersion = V1 | V2 | V3

-- | Represents the config itself, at different versions
data VersionedConfig (v :: ConfigVersion) where
  CV1 :: Int -> VersionedConfig V1
  CV2 :: Integer -> VersionedConfig V2
  CV3 :: String -> VersionedConfig V3
  
deriving instance Show (VersionedConfig v)
  
-- | Proof term for migration between versions
data MigrateableProof (from :: ConfigVersion) (to :: ConfigVersion) where
  MigrateableProof :: (VersionedConfig from -> VersionedConfig to) -> MigrateableProof from to
  
class MigrateableFromTo (from :: ConfigVersion) (to :: ConfigVersion) where
  migrateFromTo :: MigrateableProof from to
  
instance MigrateableFromTo V1 V2 where
  migrateFromTo = MigrateableProof (\(CV1 a) -> CV2 (toEnum a))
  
instance MigrateableFromTo V2 V3 where
  migrateFromTo = MigrateableProof (\(CV2 a) -> CV3 (show a))
  
instance forall from intermediate to.
  (MigrateableFromTo from intermediate, MigrateableFromTo intermediate to)
  => MigrateableFromTo from to where
  migrateFromTo = MigrateableProof (applyMigration @intermediate . applyMigration)
    
applyMigration :: MigrateableFromTo from to => VersionedConfig from -> VersionedConfig to
applyMigration = let MigrateableProof f = migrateFromTo in f 

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let
    cv1 = CV1 5
    cv3 = (applyMigration cv1) :: VersionedConfig V3
  print cv3
```

This code won't compile as `from`,`intermediate`, and `to` in the inductive instance could be the same type. Is it possible to disambiguate this such that the code compiles?

The result at present is as follows:

```hs
Main.hs:44:12: error:
    • Overlapping instances for MigrateableFromTo intermediate0 'V3
        arising from a use of ‘applyMigration’
      Matching instances:
        instance (MigrateableFromTo from intermediate,
                  MigrateableFromTo intermediate to) =>
                 MigrateableFromTo from to
          -- Defined at Main.hs:32:10
        instance MigrateableFromTo 'V2 'V3 -- Defined at Main.hs:29:10
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘intermediate0’
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    • In the expression: (applyMigration cv1) :: VersionedConfig V3
      In an equation for ‘cv3’:
          cv3 = (applyMigration cv1) :: VersionedConfig V3
      In the expression:
        do let cv1 = CV1 5
               cv3 = ...
           print cv3
   |
44 |     cv3 = (applyMigration cv1) :: VersionedConfig V3
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This code is available [in the Haskell Playground](https://play.haskell.org/saved/Ec7cOziP).

Comment: The fact that `from`, `intermediate`, and `to` could be the same type is a special case of the problem that there may not be a unique triple `(from, intermediate, to)` to turn `from` into `to`. Even if all three are unique, what instances should `MFT V1 V3` use if `MFT V1 V2a`, `MFT V1 V2b`, `MFT V2a V3`, and `MFT V2b V3` all exist? (`MFT` being an abbreviation for `MigrateableFromTo`). It may not matter if you go through `V2a` or `V2b`, but the compiler shouldn't have to, and won't, pick one arbitrarily.

Comment: If there's guaranteed to be a "straight line" of connections, I think this might be doable?

Comment: @LouisWasserman logically I can guarantee the straight line of connections, I'm just trying to figure out a way of proving it programmatically without writing an instance for every combination of config versions

Comment: I think you may be able to write something like: `class DirectlyConvertible a b | a -> b, b -> a` with functional dependencies, and then I suspect you can write `instance a ~ b => Convertible a b` and `instance (Convertible a b, DirectlyConvertible b c) => Convertible a c`, which unambiguously left-associates the conversion.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes, that works, indeed. Rather surprising it's that easy. You should make it an answer.

Comment: @notquiteamonad One thing I wasn't totally clear on (though I mention it at the end of my answer): Are there ever better ways to migrate than to go through each successive migration? If so, is the migration function expected to find any of those better ways? Or should it just do successive migrations until it reaches the goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Deep breath:

```
{-# Language AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# Language DataKinds #-}
{-# Language FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications #-}
{-# Language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# Language TypeOperators #-}
{-# Language UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
```

Here's the one-step class that you need to write instances for:

```
class DirectlyConvertible a where
    type DirectConversion a
    convertDirectly :: a -> DirectConversion a
```

And here's the supporting machinery that need only be done once:

```
class ConvertibleVia (path :: [*]) tgt where
    type From path tgt
    convert_ :: From path tgt -> tgt

instance ConvertibleVia '[] a where
    type From '[] a = a
    convert_ = id

instance (DirectlyConvertible a, DirectConversion a ~ From path c, ConvertibleVia path c) => ConvertibleVia (a:path) c where
    type From (a:path) c = a
    convert_ = convert_ @path . convertDirectly

type family ConversionPath a b where
    ConversionPath a a = '[]
    ConversionPath a b = a : ConversionPath (DirectConversion a) b

-- tiny wrapper to make the type applications a bit more convenient
convert :: forall src tgt path. (path ~ ConversionPath src tgt, ConvertibleVia path tgt, From path tgt ~ src) => src -> tgt
convert = convert_ @path
```

With that in place, we can toss in some mock instances:

```
data V1
data V2
data V3
data V4
instance DirectlyConvertible V1 where type DirectConversion V1 = V2
instance DirectlyConvertible V2 where type DirectConversion V2 = V3
instance DirectlyConvertible V3 where type DirectConversion V3 = V4
```

And now you can write e.g. `convert @V1 @V4`, or even `convert @V1` if the `V4` can be inferred from context, and it will Just Work. Ironic that disambiguating the instance resolution is done by turning on `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, isn't it?

Comment: Right.  And _type families_ are guaranteed to have their equations tried in order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that I find particularly easy to read.

No type classes are necessary for this approach. I only give a type class at the very end to make it easier to work with. Not only that, but that type class happens to do something very familiar.

This approach is based on the observation that migration is defined entirely by what happens between *successive* versions (1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, etc). How might we talk about "version successors?"

The other key point is that we want to define a function that will take a proof that version `a` is at least as old as version `b` and give back a `MigrateableProof a b`.

I would first generalize the version type like this, which will let us talk about "successor versions":

```
data Natural = Z | S Natural
  deriving (Show)

-- | Represents different versions of a config file
type ConfigVersion = Natural

type V1 = Z
type V2 = S V1
type V3 = S V2
```

There are upsides and downsides to this. The main upside is that you can easily talk about successor versions. You can also now talk about any future versions. That might be seen as a downside if you only want to talk about versions that already exist. I don't think this is too much of a downside though. We will get to that next.

We re-implement `VersionedConfig` like this:

```
-- | Represents the config itself, at different versions
data VersionedConfig (v :: ConfigVersion) where
  CV1 :: Int -> VersionedConfig V1
  CV2 :: Integer -> VersionedConfig V2
  CV3 :: String -> VersionedConfig V3
```

This only uses the versions that actually exist. This is why I don't think it's much of a downside that we now can represent non-existent versions in the `ConfigVersion` type.

Now, we can implement a function which (only) migrates a version to its successor:

```
migrateToSuccessor :: MigrateableProof from (S from)
migrateToSuccessor = MigrateableProof $ \case
  CV1 a ->    -- 1 -> 2
    CV2 (toEnum a)

  CV2 a ->    -- 2 -> 3
    CV3 (show a)
```

Before we generalize, we need a way to express proofs that a version is less than or equal to another version:

```
data (:<=) :: Natural -> Natural -> Type where
  Refl :: a :<= a
  LtS :: a :<= b -> a :<= S b

deriving instance Show (a :<= b)
```

From this, we can get the general migration function:

```
migrate :: from :<= to -> MigrateableProof from to
migrate Refl = id
migrate (LtS prf) = migrateToSuccessor . migrate prf
```

Note that I've used a `Category` instance for `MigrateableProof` to make that more readable.<sup>[1]</sup> The instance is defined like this:

```
instance Category MigrateableProof where
  id = MigrateableProof id
  MigrateableProof p . MigrateableProof q = MigrateableProof (p . q)
```

So far, we haven't needed any type classes but constructing `:<=` proofs is tedious. In order to simplify this, we can make a type class that will automatically generate `:<=` values (proofs) where appropriate:

```
class Le a b where
  le :: a :<= b

instance Le Z Z where
  le = Refl

instance forall a b. Le a b => Le (S a) (S b) where
  le =
    case le @a @b of
      Refl -> Refl
      LtS prf -> LtS (leStepBoth prf)

leStepBoth :: a :<= b -> S a :<= S b
leStepBoth Refl = Refl
leStepBoth (LtS prf) = LtS $ leStepBoth prf
```

Finally, we can define `applyMigration` and rewrite `main` like this:

```
applyMigration :: from :<= to -> VersionedConfig from -> VersionedConfig to
applyMigration prf = let MigrateableProof f = migrate prf in f

main :: IO ()
main =
  let
    cv1 = CV1 5
    cv3 = applyMigration le cv1 :: VersionedConfig V3
  in
  print cv3
```

#### Pros and cons

A drawback of this is that we are using a runtime representation of `:<=` proofs which is probably a bit less efficient than if it was resolved entirely at compile-time. I think it's very unlikely that this will be a performance bottleneck in an actual application, though.

Besides, we need to construct a `MigrateableProof` value regardless. Think of it like this: `migrate` turns a proof of `a :<= b` into a "migrateable proof" from version `a` to version `b`.

On the other hand, a *benefit* of this is that we minimize the usage of polymorphically recursive type classes and type class tricks in general. Such type classes can otherwise be somewhat complicated. I think separating things out like this makes the code more clear and better organized.

A limitation is that this approach can only express migrations that are exclusively given by "successor migrations."

I think it would be possible to modify the approach to allow for other migrations as well (for example, if there is a better way to migrate `1 -> 6` than going through each successor migration).

If you want to make this improvement, the key initial observations for this are probably:

1. The "structure" of `:<=` is "thin." To put it another way: For any versions `a` and `b`, `a :<= b` can only hold in at most *one* way.<sup>[2]</sup>
2. The `migrate` function reflects the structure of the `:<=` value into the resulting `MigrationProof` value.<sup>[3]</sup>

At least one of those would need to be addressed.<sup>[4]</sup>

There is another limitation and a fix: `migrateToSuccessor` allows you to attempt to create the successor of the most recent version. As a result, so does `migrate`. One way to fix this is to package the code up into a module, avoid exporting `migrate` and `applyMigration` and instead export these constrained functions:

```
type VersionInBound a = Le a V3

migrateSafe :: (VersionInBound to, Le from to) => MigrateableProof from to
migrateSafe = migrate le

applyMigration :: (VersionInBound to, Le from to) => VersionedConfig from -> VersionedConfig to
applyMigration = let MigrateableProof f = migrate le in f
```

<sup>[1]</sup> <sup>In order to use this `Category` instance like I have, you will need `import Prelude hiding (id, (.))` to avoid name clashes as well as `import Control.Category`</sup>

<sup>[2]</sup>  <sup>Here is a theoretical point that is not necessary to understand what I've described here, but for completeness: I'm using "thin" in [this sense](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thin+category).</sup>

<sup>[3]</sup>  <sup>There is another theoretical point that explains this bulletpoint, which is also not necessary to understand: The `migrate` function is actually a functor from the `:<=` preorder category to the `MigrateableProof` category. This is the categorical reason that `migrate` "reflects the structure of `:<=` into `MigrateableProof`." To be more explicit, we run into issues because of the composition law for functors: `migrate (f . g) = migrate f . migrate g`. This is exactly what we *don't* want if there are multiple ways to migrate between versions and we want `migrate` to choose the way that's better than using successors when possible</sup>

<sup>[4]</sup>  <sup>To again state this in categorical terms using the previous two footnotes, we want to do at least one of the following two things: (1) Replace `:<=` with a category that is *not* thin. (2) Re-implement `migrate` knowing that it should *not* be a functor.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice approach but not what I'm looking for given other constraints around the ConfigVersion type I'm bound by. Very interesting though. To respond to your comment on the question - no, I'm not planning on any non-direct paths for optimisation at this point so as far as that's concerned this fits perfectly.